# Simple Query to get exact result

Tags: mysql, sql, oledb

Respected Users,

I one table called Employee as follows

```
EmpId | EmpName | ManagerId
 1        Smith    10
 2        John     11
 10       Ted       2
 11       Lowson    1
```

Every employee has a manager. each manager is Employee.

Now, I want to write a query such that All the employee names with their manager names.

I tried something like this>>>

```
select a.EmpName,b.EmpName from Employee a,b where b.ManagerId=a.EmpId
```

but failed.

Kindly guid me.

Comment: If an employee is manage than what will be is managgerId will hold?

Comment: ManagerId is employee Id only

Comment: i think it will be 0 (zero)

Comment: what 0? i could not understand

Comment: hahahah all answers are in minus :) , sounds no one is right :)

Comment: not able to unserstand which one is correct

Comment: if you want to select the empl even if they dont have managers then choose the answer with LEFT JOIN

Comment: @goodmood It needs to be a left join, because a manager has no manager.

Comment: @goodmood please look at the query by PeteH...is that query and query written by me is same?

Comment: @tombom if you look at the table data it shows managers also have managers

Comment: @freelancer yes its same :)

Comment: @goodmood is the query by Adeel Ahmed and Sashi Kant is correct as you are suggesting left joins and each one of them is upvoted. i will not be able to check correctness by tommorrow.

Comment: @freelancer they are right of adeel ahmed , sashi ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,,

```
select 
t1.EmpName as EmoName, t2.EmpName as ManagerName
from   Employee t1 
LEFT join Employee t2 on t1.ManagerId = t2.EmpId
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this ::

```
select 
t1.EmpName as EmoName, t2.EmpName as ManagerName
from   Employee t1 
LEFT join Employee t2 on t1.ManagerId = t2.EmpId
```

Comment: why this is just copy past code of @AdeelAhmed ?? or just to get the upvote ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like homework:

Your statement misses the `FROM` clause. And you should read up on `JOINs`. You have to join the table to itself to get the Manager for each employee. Another hint (because all other answers fail in that point): you will need a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: this good method to downvote all to stay only you in play stadium

Comment: I downvoted because they don't left join. And I will remove downvote when they correct it.

Comment: from clause is missed by me while writting the question. I will Edit it

Comment: Read question properly before answering.

Comment: Let's see, so instead of posting the answer yourself you just tell how to get at the answer and then down vote others who try and mess up.  Then remove your down vote once they correct themselves, but in the process end up with a down vote for yourself (not mine) because someone thinks your a douche bag.  This might be a good time for you to reflect and consider how the effect of your approach here might be affecting you in real life as well.

Comment: you right @BrandonMoore , i dont like people like that , at least he say his note to let you correct , he do like that to let his post in positiv and yours in negativ and his post will be accepted .

Comment: @goodmood It was not to let my answer stay on top. I don't like the people who try to post an answer as quickly as possible just to get some reputation and don't read the question properly. So I think, the fact that I remove my downvotes is in fact a nice side of mine. Also I don't like the people who present the right answer straight when the OP clearly is in the process of learning something. But he won't learn something by copy&pasting the answers given here.

Comment: And that is why I won't delete my answer no matter how many downvotes I get.

Comment: This is the best way to answer in this forum, showing the OP how to do that, not posting the complete answer, giving the OP to learn, 
+1 :-)

Comment: @BrandonMoore You should read my comment directed to goodmood, too.

Comment: Not surprisingly, my attack on your not providing the actual answer has caused you to completely miss the point of my comment.

Comment: Then explain me again, please, what your point is. At the moment I must assume, **you** didn't get **my** point.

Comment: @tombom i understand you , it was nice what u doing to let people understand , but i think it let them be nervous when they see the downvote . not all people understand really what the questionar said , so they try to help , but by your side i mean note them ,comment them . and if they dont correct , or the answer doesnt solve the question , or very away of the question then you can downvote . its same for you if you have seen 3 downvotes before and u deleted it , it feels not good or ? sorry , thx again for trying to let people understand .

Comment: You are right, @goodmood, actually I could have written a detailed explanation, why it has to be left join. I let my personal mood influence my work on this site today, which is wrong. Sorry.

Comment: you was the first one who said about left join and they were wrong i know and u deserve ++ for this .

Answer (score 0):

at its most basic...

```
select emp.EmpName, mgr.EmpName
from Employee emp, Employee mgr
where emp.ManagerId = mgr.EmpId
```

You will most likelyneed something more complex that this to cover off e.g. employees who do not have managers, but this query is a start for you.

Comment: is this query and query written by me is same?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
 group_concat(t2.EmpName SEPARATOR ',') AS empName,t1.ManagerId from 
  Employee t1 join Employee t2 on t1.ManagerId = t2.EmpId
  where t1.ManagerId = 0
 group by t1.ManagerId
```

You will get result as

EmpName (Lowson,Td,Jon)       Manager (MangerName)

So result will in a single row only

Answer (score 0):

Try this you missed something

```
select a.EmpName,b.EmpName from Employee a, Employee b where b.ManagerId=a.EmpId
```

Comment: That is the same as the LEFT join answer.  Except the LEFT join will include the main boss employee who would have a null manager field.  (The example has a circular relationship, in the real world someone would be the main boss).